# Possible to do cable & wireless syncing with Blackberry Enterprise Server?

Tags: blackberry, bes

Using Blackberry Enterprise Server, is there a way to sync both wirelessly and via the sync cable?  As in, can you make contacts sync via the cable and then the calendar and email sync wirelessly?  Additionally, if you can sync contacts locally with the usb cable, can you sync both your regular outlook contact list and a Public Contact list without using a 3rd party application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use both the blackberry desktop manager (via USB cable) and the wireless sync with the enterprise server, doesn't matter which one you use, but you can use both at the same time.

I believe each different type of service gives you the option if you want to sync wirelessly or not within the options section of the blackberry.

I don't know of a way to sync the public contact list out of the box.